# How to disable kendo grid filter Icons in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, kendo-grid, angular5, kendo-autocomplete

I am using kendo grid for displaying data, [filterable]="true" in web page showing filters, but i want hide only filter icon button. i tried css but it is not working. can you please help me on that.I tried bellow code but not working.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [filterable]="true",    [filterable.extra]="false"><kendo-grid> <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"    [filterable]="true", [filterable.cell.enabled]="false"><kendo-grid>
```

css:

```
span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header.k-dropdown-operator {
    display: none;
}
```

I am new to kendo-grid, angular2/5 and typescript, can you please help me.

Comment: Do you mean the filter will be exist and icon not?

Comment: Try:  `.k-i-filter k-icon{display:none;}`

Comment: tried, not working

Comment: filter will be exist and icon not:yes

Comment: you mean the button filter will be empty

Comment: filter icon button , i need to hide

Comment: It works for me in runTime...

Comment: i tryied, not working

Comment: Can you try do add `!important` to the `display:none!important;`

Comment: i tried. that one also, even i tried bellow code :display:none !important; width:0px;height;0px;overflow:hidden;

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/need-to-change-filter-icon-in-grid-columns

Comment: instead of  `background-image` put `display:none`

Comment: i tried no use, i think we need to add script

Comment: Tell me if it helps.....

Comment: do u work with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in this question, my understanding is that, OP wants the icon on the filter to be gone. If so, try this. I just tested it. Should work for filter (Not clear filter icon)

```
span.k-i-filter.k-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: will you please elaborate how this works? i need to achive the filter icon gone.

Comment: This is just css. Include it in the page the grid is on. The classes mentioned here is only applicable to filter, hence display:none will remove the filter

Comment: it is working whne i add the class on global style.css but when i put it on the components associate style.css it is not working. do you have any idea why?

Comment: You may have to ask a separate SO question on how to apply CSS styles properly with your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
      <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell
        [showOperators]="false"
        [column]="column"
        [filter]="filter">
      </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Use this code sample, You can hide the filter ICON. 100% working.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-hiding-row-filter-operators

(search under - Hiding Row Filter Operators)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [showOperators]="false". This will remove the kendo filter icon.